# Insert record from one table to another table by using select statement

Tags: mysql

here i am trying to insert patient_id and nurse_id which are from two different tables.

`insert into nurse_take_care(patient_id,nurse_id) values (patient_id(select MAX(p_id) from patient;), nurse_id(Select n_id from nurse order by Rand() limit 1;))`

is this the right way to do??

Comment: No. See `INSERT INTO... SELECT`. And there's no situation in which you would insert MAX(p_id). In this context, such a query is potentially lethal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try this 
 `insert into nurse_take_care(patient_id,nurse_id)
SELECT (select MAX(p_id) from patient) as p_id, (select n_id from nurse order by Rand() limit 1) as n_id`

Answer (score 0):

The query would be like:

```
insert into nurse_take_care(patient_id,nurse_id) values 
(select MAX(p_id) from patient limit 1, Select n_id from nurse order by Rand() limit 1);
```

Comment: Did you try this? @Rahul Varma

Comment: Do not need `LIMIT 1` in the patient subquery as it would cut to the first row, thus making `MAX()` ineffective.

Comment: if he adds group by later that will create problem so that i added limit

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO nurse_take_care (patient_id, nurse_id)
SELECT ( SELECT MAX(p_id) FROM patient ),
       ( SELECT n_id FROM nurse ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 )
```